# i need a hack to make xslt let us set new values for variables

Tags: xml, xslt

I've read that unlike programming languages, XSLT does not allow us to set a new value to a variable. I'm just wondering is there any hacks to get around this limitation that people are using? because having the ability to reset the value of a *variable* is inherently useful AFAIK

Well at least if we could reset the value of a variable, I could solve my problem here: [how do i not repeat repeated logic in my xslt code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296656/how-do-i-not-repeat-repeated-logic-in-my-xslt-code)

Comment: I usually avoid side-effects of variables when I can. Have a specific example?

Comment: You're making the mistake of assuming XSLT works like other procedural languages.  It can be twisted so that it looks kinda like it's procedural, but fundamentally it is not.  It's a functional language, and changeable variables would make it very hard to debug (and to implement).  I'm sure the XSL luminaries on SO (Dimitre, Michael Kay, and others) can do a much better job of explaining this, which is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Maybe if you described the problem you're trying to solve, we can help you learn how to use XSLT the way it was intended...

Comment: +1, really liked this question.

Comment: Some of us were around when Dijkstra introduced goto-less programming, and lots of practising programmers complained, saying GOTO statements were really useful. Then as now the answer to the complaint is: show us your problem, and we'll show you an elegant solution that doesn't require assignment|goto statements. In time you'll learn that without assignment statements, you write better code.

Comment: i've edited the question with an example on how setting a variable will be useful

Comment: @Jim Garrison see my edited question

Comment: @Michael Kay . i agree with you that many stuff turned out right in the end, though i agree that there are many stuff which turned out wrong in the end too

Comment: @Michael Kay . btw i've edited the question with a problem that requires an elegant solution which doesn't require setting a variable to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've read that unlike programming
>   languages, XSLT does not allow us to
>   set a new value to a variable.

**Two incorrect statements here**:

1. "unlike programming languages, XSLT". XSLT *is* a programming language. It is a member of a group of programming languages called Functional Programmin Languages. The closest correct statement to what you are trying to say is: "unlike *procedural" programming languages"
2. "XSLT does not allow us to set a new value to a variable". Again incorrect -- it is not XSLT that doesn't allow something -- it is any functional programming language, and XSLT is a functional programming language.

> I'm just wondering is there any hacks
>   to get around this limitation that
>   people are using?

There are *no* hacks as people don't need such hacks. People who cannot live without being able to change the value of a variable, simply use a procedural programming language.

> because having the
>   ability to reset the value of a
>   variable is inherently useful AFAIK

**Actually, having such an ability is harmful in most cases**. It makes much more difficult to understand a program and/or to prove it correct with program correctness verifiers. Any program with side effects is also more difficult to optimize and any such programs may be less optimized than immutable code that also solves the same problem.

**It is good to know**: It is wellknown that any program that can be solved with a procedural language can also be solved with a functional language. Therefore, one doesn't need a mutable variable -- there isn't even a single problem that cannot be solved in a functional way. That *you* think the problem is unsolvable in a functional way doesn't really make this problem unsolvable -- just ask other people and they will show you a neat solution -- often much shorter and much more elegant than a procedural solution.

**A good example what can be done with pure XSLT** is the **[FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)** library. FXSL provides a set of functions/templates of solving large classes of problems, among them quite complicated ones such as finding any power (`x^y`) or logarithm, or the basic trigonometric functions, or solving any equation `f(x) = 0`, etc. ...

**Other examples of FXSL functions** are in the area of text-processing -- word tokenization, spelling checking, concordance building, etc. ...

**Even more complex tasks implemented with FXSL functions**: a generic LR-1 parser, parsers for JSON and for XPath 2.0, generation of a sequence of random numbers, numerical integration and differentiation, ..., etc.

**All this is done without changing any variables** -- not a bit disconvenienced by the fact that "XSLT doesn't allow this" :)

Comment: i think `any functional programming language` in point 2 is an oversimplification

Answer (score 3):

XSLT variables have to be intended in the traditional sense of mathematics, and not as variables in the common sense of procedural languages like C++.

> XSLT does not allow us to set a new value to a variable.

Actually is not that really true, in the sense that variable are scoped in the XSLT element they are contained.

Therefore, if you define a variable as child of `xsl:stylesheet` you have to treat it like a global constant.

But if you define a variable as child of `xsl:template`, while you have to treat your variable like a local constant in the *current context* of the template only, in the scope of the transform you can think of it as a variable which can take a **different** value according to the template *context*. The same applies to named template or functions.

> is there any hacks to get around this limitation?

Just get used to work with them in a functional way.

---

Abstract example:

If you define a variable as child of `xsl:stylesheet` so that they get values according to the transform parameters, you can think the variable as a variable in the scope of the transform.

So think a stylesheet with parameters as a function:

```
F(x)
```

and a template with a variable, as a sub-function within the `F(x)`, let say:

```
T(y)
```

So that you can have the abstract:

```
F(x) = G( T(y), x )
```

you can also have, for example:

```
F(x) = G( T(y(x)), x )
```

depending on how you design your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT, you have constants, not variables. No idea why they call them variables. They don't vary. They're constant. The only hack I know of is to hack your mind into understanding XSLT. Not the best solution, I know...but that's XSLT.

Comment: They are called variables after the traditional usage in mathematics: in the formula area = length × width, length and width are referred to as variables because they have a different value each time you use the formula.

Comment: Ah, that does make sense! Clarity.