# XSL: selecting data from a node based on the value of a variable

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working on a minor project learning XSL, and I've run across a problem...

I have a Docbook file with a series of entires for people categorized by Department. Occasionally, however, I will have a person who works in a minor group as well as his own. To avoid duplication of data, I specified that a person node either contains the data in their node, or an xref node that links to their main node. When I iterate over all people in a group, I need to check whether the node is a linked node or a data node and adjust my variables accordingly.

Here's the choose code

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="xref">
        <xsl:variable name="TAG_ID" select="xref/@linkend" />
        <xsl:variable name="NAME" select="//*[@id='$TAG_ID']/para[@id='who']" />
        <xsl:variable name="EMAIL" select="//*[@id='$TAG_ID']/para[@id='who']/ulink/@url" />
        <xsl:variable name="IMAGE" select="//*[@id='$TAG_ID']/para[@id='image']" />
        <xsl:variable name="MEET" select="//*[@id='$TAG_ID']/para[@id='meet']" />
        <xsl:call-template name="output_person" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:variable name="NAME" select="para[@id ='who']" />
        <xsl:variable name="EMAIL" select="para[@id='who']/ulink/@url" />
        <xsl:variable name="IMAGE" select="para [@id='image']" />
        <xsl:variable name="MEET" select="para [@id='meet']" />
        <xsl:call-template name="output_person" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

However, when I try to run this I get the following errors...

```
runtime error: file team.xsl line 92 element img
Variable 'IMAGE' has not been declared.
xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed
```

After some looking on the internet, I have simultaneously seen code that accomplishes this and people saying its impossible.

So my question is twofold...

Can I select a specific node based on an variable?

and if not, can this even be done?

Comment: Line 92 is contained inside the "output_person" template. My main problem is the error xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed.

Comment: The error seems mentioning an used variable (`$IMAGE`) which is undeclared. However there is no `$IMAGE` variable in the code you are showing. Perhaps your _choose code_ is the wrong choice :) to give us the correct context. More, that does not look like the correct way to declare variables.

Comment: See, this is why I post here. I was under the impression that you used the <csl:variable> command to create a variable, and within attributes you could use a variable by preceding the name with a $, Perl style. What is the correct way to use a variable?

Comment: The code you are showing is just declaring variables inside the `xsl:choose` sub-elements. Then you call a named template without using the variables. So what's the purpose of that? If you don't know `xsl:variable` works in XSLT you can see this recent [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287983/i-need-a-hack-to-make-xslt-let-us-set-new-values-for-variables/6288473#6288473); otherwise just try to clarify your input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables you are declaring will not be in scope for your output_person template. In order for this to work, you need to have the output_person template accept params and then pass those params as part of [call-template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#named-templates).

Also note that references to variables shouldn't be enclosed in quotes.

For example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<!-- other templates -->
<xsl:template match="your-element">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="xref">
            <xsl:variable name="TAG_ID" select="xref/@linkend" />
            <xsl:variable name="NAME" select="//*[@id=$TAG_ID]/para[@id='who']" />
            <xsl:variable name="EMAIL" select="//*[@id=$TAG_ID]/para[@id='who']/ulink/@url" />
            <xsl:variable name="IMAGE" select="//*[@id=$TAG_ID]/para[@id='image']" />
            <xsl:variable name="MEET" select="//*[@id=$TAG_ID]/para[@id='meet']" />
            <xsl:call-template name="output_person">
               <xsl:with-param name="NAME" select="$NAME"/> 
                <xsl:with-param name="EMAIL" select="$EMAIL"/> 
                <xsl:with-param name="IMAGE" select="$IMAGE"/> 
                <xsl:with-param name="MEET" select="$MEET"/> 
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:variable name="NAME" select="para[@id ='who']" />
            <xsl:variable name="EMAIL" select="para[@id='who']/ulink/@url" />
            <xsl:variable name="IMAGE" select="para [@id='image']" />
            <xsl:variable name="MEET" select="para [@id='meet']" />
            <xsl:call-template name="output_person">
                <xsl:with-param name="NAME" select="$NAME"/> 
                <xsl:with-param name="EMAIL" select="$EMAIL"/> 
                <xsl:with-param name="IMAGE" select="$IMAGE"/> 
                <xsl:with-param name="MEET" select="$MEET"/> 
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="output_person">
    <xsl:param name="NAME"/>
    <xsl:param name="EMAIL"/>
    <xsl:param name="IMAGE"/>
    <xsl:param name="MEET"/>
    <!-- your logic here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is not correct. You can't declare the same variable two times. And this rule applies to any programming language, but those working with untyped variables.

Comment: I think it is correct: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#local-variables Here's the spec ref: "As well as being allowed at the top-level, both xsl:variable and xsl:param are also allowed in templates. xsl:variable is allowed anywhere within a template that an instruction is allowed. In this case, the binding is visible for all following siblings and their descendants."

Comment: I was referring to the `xsl:choose`. However it looks ok, you are right. I was wrong.

Comment: +1 for the right direction. Even if I imagine the OP is also using the declared variables out of scope.

Comment: Tried this - worked like a charm, although I need to work out why my link node selects arnt working... but thats a problem I can figure out. Thanks all!